# How to prevent making multiple .json files in the fixture folder while using cy.intercep for the same endpoint with Cypress Javascript

Tags: javascript, methods, cypress, fixtures, cy.intercept

At this point I am stubbing API endpoints with Cypress Intercept.
It is working great, but I've the feeling I could use it more efficient.

Currently I have the following test:

```
 cy.intercept('GET', '**/Classifications', { fixture: 'stubClassifications/Classifications5.json' })
        cy.get('div.dropdown-menu.show').find('a.dropdown-item').should('have.length', 5)
```

It's working, and checks the file Classifications5.json where 5 classifications are available.:

[image]

Classifications5.json:

```
 [
  {
    "id": "6a75b703-8af4-4734-8d3f-c259d36b7a5e",
    "name": "1STUBTest EEO",
    "hasChildren": false
  },

  {
    "id": "6a75b703-8af4-4734-8d3f-c259d36b7a5e",
    "name": "2STUBTest EEO",
    "hasChildren": false
  },

  {
    "id": "6a75b703-8af4-4734-8d3f-c259d36b7a5e",
    "name": "3STUBTest EEO",
    "hasChildren": false
  },
  {
    "id": "6a75b703-8af4-4734-8d3f-c259d36b7a5e",
    "name": "4STUBTest EEO",
    "hasChildren": false
  },
  {
    "id": "6a75b703-8af4-4734-8d3f-c259d36b7a5e",
    "name": "5STUBTest EEO",
    "hasChildren": false
  }
]
```

In a following test I am stubbing the same API-endpoint but with just 1 classification, namely Classifications1.json.

As you can understand I made several .json file in the fixture map for each result that I am asserting and this doesn't look very nice and clean.

How can I prevent making multiple .json files in the map fixtures when using the cy.intercept for the same end-point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are saying that `Classifications1.json` is a smaller version of `Classifications5.json`?

If so you only need the  `Classifications5.json` file. Smaller files can be derived from it.

```js
cy.fixture('Classifications5.json').then(fiveItems => 
  const oneItem = fiveItems.slice(0,1)
  cy.intercept('GET', '**/Classifications', oneItem)
```

In a two-item test

```js
cy.fixture('Classifications5.json').then(fiveItems => 
  const twoItems = fiveItems.slice(0,2)
  cy.intercept('GET', '**/Classifications', twoItems)
```

**Generating the fixture**

If the only thing that changes is the `name` property, you could generate the fixture on the fly.

```js
const generateFixture = (numItems) => {
  const fixture = [...Array(numItems).keys()].map(key => {
    return {
      id: "6a75b703-8af4-4734-8d3f-c259d36b7a5e",
      name: `${key}STUBTest EEO`,
      hasChildren: false
    }
  })
  return fixture
}

...

const twoItems = generateFixture(2)
cy.intercept('GET', '**/Classifications', twoItems)
```

Comment: Hi Fody! Thanks for your amazing answer :) .slice method seems to work.

But your second solution gives me the following error:

"Array(...).keys(...).Map is not a function"

What would be the solution for this? Because this really looks a nice and effective method.

Comment: Sorry I missed some brackets.